# Java show Year only

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a Java application that allows me to customize reports. The report uses tags for things like dates and names etc.

I have this tag: `<[ECHO text="dateFormat.format(currentDate)"/]>`

which puts out the current date like this:

`May 23, 2014`

but I just want the year like this:

`2014`

How do I do that?

EDIT:

I tried: `<[ECHO text="dateFormat.format('yyyy', currentDate)"/]>`

But I get this error:

```
com.agilemind.commons.modules.dynatags.TagValueEvaluationException: Error happened during evaluating 'dateFormat.format('yyyy', currentDate) ' of 'text' of 'ECHO' tag
    at com.agilemind.commons.modules.dynatags.advanced.b.evaluate(b.java:12)
    at com.agilemind.commons.modules.dynatags.advanced.EchoTag.transform(EchoTag.java:6)
    at com.agilemind.commons.modules.dynatags.TagBodyElement.transform(TagBodyElement.java:9)
    at com.agilemind.commons.modules.dynatags.Body.transform(Body.java:4)
    at com.agilemind.commons.modules.dynatags.BodyTag.transform(BodyTag.java:55)
    at com.agilemind.commons.modules.dynatags.TagBodyElement.transform(TagBodyElement.java:9)
    at com.agilemind.commons.modules.dynatags.Body.transform(Body.java:4)
    at com.agilemind.commons.modules.dynatags.BodyTag.transform(BodyTag.java:55)
    at com.agilemind.commons.modules.dynatags.RootTag.transform(RootTag.java:18)
    ... 23 more
```

Thanks
C

Comment: set format pattern to `yyyy`

Comment: Your `DateFormat` needs to only accommodate `yyyy`.

Comment: @Mak no it needs `yyyy`

Comment: I tried ('yyyy', currentDate) but I got an error

Comment: What error?  Putting both what you attempted and the error you got would be helpful.

Comment: pattern is passed in constructor of `SimpleDateFormat` where you construct instance

Comment: In your example tag, is the text in quotes actually java language code? Are you able to control how the `dateFormat` object is initialized? Are you able to initialize a different date formatter object and use it there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
```

now your code:

```
<[ECHO text="dateFormat.format(currentDate)"/]>
```

should give you the correct output.

Comment: Thanks.. I defined an new variable in the head:

<[DEFINE name="dateFormat" value="reportData.createDateFormat('MMM d, yyyy', 'en')"/]>
<[DEFINE name="yearFormat" value="reportData.createDateFormat('yyyy', 'en')"/]>

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu" ) ; // Use just the year of the date-time.
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

> 2018

## Joda-Time

Using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, you could use a formatter to generate a string similar to the other answer.

Another solution is to extract the year number.

```
int year = DateTime.now().getYear();
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).